# get entire line with java.util.scanner.hasNext(regex)

Tags: java, regex, input, line, java.util.scanner

I'm doing something in Java that requires input to be matched against the pattern ^[1-5]$. I should have a while loop looping through each line of input, checking it against the pattern, and outputting an error message if it does not.

Sudo code:

```
while (regex_match(/^[^1-5]$/,inputLine)) {  
    print ("Please enter a number between 1 and 5! ");  
    getNextInputLine();
}
```

I can use `java.util.Scanner.hasMatch("^[^1-5]$")`, but that will only match a single token, not the entire line. Any idea on how to make hasMatch match against the entire line? (Setting the delimiter to "\n" or "\0" doesn't work.)

Edit: If this isn't possible, is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Scanner has no such method:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking exactly.

- [`hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) can tell you if there's an [`int nextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29). You can then check if it's between 1-5, and if it isn't prompt for another. This would seem to be the cleanest option, without even using regex.
- [`hasNext("[1-5]")`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) can tell you if the entirety of the next token is a `nextInt()` between 1-5. This is actually a bit strict in that if the next token is, say, `"005"`, it doesn't match. You can make the regex more complicated to accommodate this, but at that point the first option above becomes even more attractive.
- [`findInLine(String pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.lang.String%29) can find a pattern, ignoring delimiters, skipping any input that doesn't match. You can extract the number from an input like `"I want to buy 3 apples, please!"`, for example. This likely isn't what you need (but it isn't clear from the question).

---

Another possibility is that perhaps not only do you need the next token to be `^[1-5]$`, but you want *the entire next line* to match that. If that's the case, then maybe something like this is what you need:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
if (!line.matches("^[1-5]$")) {
  // error message
} else {
  int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
}
```

If you want to check if the `nextLine()` matches that pattern *without* consuming that line, then you can do the following:

```
if (scanner.findInLine("^[1-5]$") != null) {
  // nextLine().matches("[1-5]");
}
```